# Grab the part of a text with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

Can someone please help me to grab a part of text.

```
var conf={key:'0ffab2f5f9fa64dc571',playlist:[{url:'URL',scaling:'scale',thumbnail:{'url':''}},{url:escape('URL'),autoPlay:false,scaling:'fit',provider:'lighttpd',autoBuffering:false,thumbnail:{url:'URL',thumbWidth:'100',thumbHeight:'56'}}],plugins:{controls:{url:'URL',timeColor:'#FFFFFF',backgroundColor:'#000000',autoHide:{enabled:false,fullscreenOnly:true},tooltipColor:'#FFFFFF',tooltipTimeColor:'#000000',tooltipTimeAlign:'BOTTOM_RIGHT',scrubberHeightRatio:1,scrubberBarHeightRatio:0.5},lighttpd:{url:'URL',queryString:escape('start=${start}')}},canvas:{backgroundColor:'#202020',backgroundGradient:'none'}}
    var hwurl='URL';
```

I would like to grab that URL part of `url:escape('URL')`

So far i tried this but didn't work;

```
if (preg_match("/url:escape('(.*?)')/", $data, $match)){
$st = urldecode($match[1]);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have forget to escape regex reserved characters like `(` eg.

see a list here http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

```
preg_match("#url:escape\('(.*)'\)#siU", $data, $match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is good, the only thing you must do is to escape literal parenthesis.

Comment: can you give an example please?